# Is it possible to pass an argument to npm scripts and use that inline to set an ENV_VAR?

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-scripts

Example npm scripts:

```
{
    ...
    "build": "BUILD_FLAG=$argv node ...",
    ...
}
```

Then call it like `npm run build prod`

This obviously doesn't work, but is there another way to do this?

I am aware you can pass flags to other npm scripts with `--`, but I want do to this from the command line.

Comment: there are other options, but they will vary depending on what shell environment you are using, i.e. `powershell`, `cmd`, `bash`, etc....

Comment: `bash` is fine. If you could point me to something that would be great, haven't had much luck looking.

Comment: well your question is a bit strange, since in this case you could just do `BUILD_FLAG=prod npm run build`....  I don't know what you are saving by trying to read an argument.

Comment: Actually, I want to `npm run build` with `prod` as the argument, but it's not being sent